# Get specific values from the console with python

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to know how I can obtain specific data from a json that is displayed in the console.

I invoke the function and it returns this to me.

```
async def gouser(ctx):
    print(clientp.user.list_users("test@gmail.com"))
```

```
{'object': 'list', 'data': [{'object': 'user', 'attributes': {'id': 1, 'external_id': None, 'uuid'
'dd1de66d-504e-4cbf-84aa-3b3e89c8d641', 'username': 'admin', 'email': 'test@gmail.com', 'fir
_name': 'a', 'last_name': 'a', 'language': 'en', 'root_admin': True, '2fa': False, 'created_at': '
21-08-20T15:27:25+00:00', 'updated_at': '2021-08-20T15:27:25+00:00'}}], 'meta': {'pagination': {'t
al': 1, 'count': 1, 'per_page': 50, 'current_page': 1, 'total_pages': 1, 'links': {}}}}
```

I tried using this method but it returns an error.

```
async def gouser(ctx):
    tes = clientp.user.list_users("test@gmail.com")
    id = tes['data']['attributes']['id']
    print(id)
```

This is the error

```
Ignoring exception in command gouser:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "index.py", line 134, in gouser
    id = tes['data']['attributes']
KeyError: 'attributes'
```

Comment: Key `data` is a list, try `tes['data'][0]['attributes']['id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the `tes['data']` points to a list, so you'll need something like

```
async def gouser(ctx):
    tes = clientp.user.list_users("test@gmail.com")
    id = tes['data'][0]['attributes']['id']
    print(id)
```

From discussion: `test` is actually from class `pydactyl.responses.PaginatedResponse`, which has its own `'data'`, so the access is missing another `['data']` and it should be:

`id = tes['data']['data'][0]['attributes']['id']`

Comment: I tried to see and I got the same error `File "index.py", line 134, in gouser id = tes['data'][0]['attributes']['id'] KeyError: 0`

Comment: You should print out `tes['data']` and see what the structure of the data is. It's possible that your data is being returned in an inconsistent format.

Comment: I just printed data and this is the value returned https://pastebin.com/VHjkx2dS

Comment: Did you save your code/is the version of the code running the most up-to-date?

Comment: It is the same code, the only thing that changed was to eliminate `[0] ['attributes'] ['id']` and only leave `[data]` to print

Comment: Oh, you might be missing another ['data'] then. Try printing out `tes` and verifying the structure.

Comment: When you print only `tes`, it returns the same value as if you printed `id = tes ['data']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236304/discussion-between-andrew-wei-and-axel-garcia).

Answer (score 0):

The printed result is serialized(by __str__()), and the true content is not same with the show. But if you don't care about some performance loss, this can be helped:

```
async def gouser(ctx):
    import json
    res = json.loads(str(clientp.user.list_users("test@gmail.com")))
    return res
```

Comment: Maybe, but indexing into a string with another string, i.e. `"abc"['attributes']` doesn't produce a KeyError, it produces `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean, str is similar to list, so you can only use integers as indexes. The value returned by `json.load` is a dict, and `clientp.user.list_users("test@gmail.com")` is must not a normal dict.

Comment: I think I misread your answer, I didn't see the cast to `str`. But yeah, talked to OP and `tes` is not actually a dictionary, but `tes['data']` is.

Comment: Also from discussion, json.loads expects the keys to be in double quotes, so you'd need a `.replace('\'', '"')`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm drunk, I originally wanted to use eval, but I remembered that this is not safe. In the chaos, I chose `json.loads`, and overlooked the difference between python's dict and json